# Why is string search fastest as compared to list search and set search?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I was solving some competitive coding coding challenges. My solution was exceeding time limit when I was searching in list, but was accepted when I searched in string.

Below is a sample code:

**CODE**

```
import timeit

list = timeit.Timer("'A' in list('AEIOU')")
set = timeit.Timer("'A' in set('AEIOU')")
string = timeit.Timer("'A' in 'AEIOU'")

print 'List search :',list.timeit(999999)
print 'Set search',set.timeit(999999)
print 'String search',string.timeit(999999)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
List search : 1.0873670578
Set search 1.0083398819
String search 0.0997061729431
```

*This output was obtained in ideone.com ... http://ideone.com/5FxkX2
**Output may vary from system to system but the trend is same.

I found that string search is incredibly faster. I googled but didn't found a satisfactory reasoning to this. Please help me understand why is string search fastest?

Comment: Actually, checking member ship for `set` is faster than list and string because the use hash-table and it O(1), but the different that you see here is because of converting the string to set and list. So try with `{'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'O'}` and `['A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'O']`

Comment: Because your example sets are so small the `O(1)`  for `set` advantage over the `O(N)` for the others wouldn't matter. Also the setup (creation of `set` and `list`) is `O(N)` anyway. Searching a string is faster than `list` because it's a simplier structure (it contains an array of characters rather than references to string objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has very little to do with actual search speed and everything with having to look up a global name (`set` or `list`) and calling that global (which includes a frame save and restore).

Test the actual `in` operator *alone*, not with the call:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in l", "l = list('AEIOU')").timeit(999999)
0.0490870475769043
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in s", "s = set('AEIOU')").timeit(999999)
0.0507349967956543
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in s", "s = 'AEIOU'").timeit(999999)
0.04982495307922363
```

Now the times are too close to call, because your objects are way too small. Use *much larger inputs* to actually see a difference.

Just using more characters already increases the contrast somewhat:

```
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in l", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; l = list(ascii_letters + digits + whitespace)").timeit(999999)
0.38520193099975586
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in s", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; s = set(ascii_letters + digits + whitespace)").timeit(999999)
0.046868085861206055
>>> timeit.Timer("'A' in s", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; s = ascii_letters + digits + whitespace").timeit(999999)
0.06492304801940918
```

Now `set()` objects are starting to win, and list objects show their slower speed.

You should also test for the *negative* case, where the character is *not* present in the object:

```
>>> timeit.Timer("'\xff' in l", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; l = list(ascii_letters + digits + whitespace)").timeit(999999)
0.909243106842041
>>> timeit.Timer("'\xff' in s", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; s = set(ascii_letters + digits + whitespace)").timeit(999999)
0.05034899711608887
>>> timeit.Timer("'\xff' in s", "from string import ascii_letters, digits, whitespace; s = ascii_letters + digits + whitespace").timeit(999999)
0.09932804107666016
```

Here the `set()` object really excels.

Note that the string search still beats the list search in both cases; that's because iterating over a C array and comparing bytes is faster than comparing objects in a dynamic array, where you cannot up-front know that all the objects are the same type.

Answer (score 6):

Your test is biased, you need to use the `setup` argument to neglect the time to *create* the `list` or `set`

```
>>> timeit.timeit("'A' in l", "l = list('AEIOU')")
0.06389708405846951
>>> timeit.timeit("'A' in s", "s = set('AEIOU')")
0.05960524183085081
>>> timeit.timeit("'A' in s", "s = 'AEIOU'")
0.05756433387793081
```

That being said, the `in` operation for `str` and `list` is linear `O(N)` and `set` is constant `O(1)` (neglecting lots of hash collisions). So for a much larger example, the `set` would be the fastest, and `str` and `list` would be very similar.